# How to read only the first line of the output from a file descriptor?

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I have output which is coming from fd3 from a program of which I am redirecting to a file as such:

> program 3> output.log

In this instance I only need the first line provided by the program to be written to the log and do not want to keep a write handle open to this file for the life of the program.

How can I read only the first line? I think I can use the shell command `read` but I don't know how to use it for anything other than stdout. Note that I do not want to redirect fd3 to stdout to then use `read` as I am capturing stdout to another log.

Comment: How about `program | head -1 3> output.log`

Comment: This redirects only stdout to head (ignoring fd3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the first line of an arbitrary file descriptor in this way:

```
$ (printf '%s\n' foo bar >&3) 3> >(head -n1)
foo
```

This prints two lines to FD 3 and redirects that to standard input of `head`. If you want to store that result to a file simply redirect within the [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).